# How to reopen a Hibernate Session after rollback with Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I have a general question concerning Hibernate and Apache Tomcat. Let's assume we have a webpage with a form and a submit button. The user can enter some data which will then be stored in the database.

Here is my configuration:

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <property name="connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/mia</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">${db.url}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">${db.user}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">${db.password}</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone">UTC</property>
```

My Transaction Util Class:

```
    public class TransactionManager implements ITransactionManager {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =  LoggerFactory.getLogger(TransactionManager.class.getCanonicalName());
       Transaction tx = null;
    boolean isInternalTransaction = false;
    private Session session;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see IOperationManager#beginOperation
     */
    @Override
    public Session beginOperation() {
        return beginOperation(0);
    }

    /**
     * Try to handle invalidated/inactive sessions
     * @param level recursion limit
     * @return hibernate session
     */
    private Session beginOperation(int level) {
        if (level > 1) {
            throw new HibernateException("Cannot create hibernate session.");
        }
        else {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            LOGGER.trace("Session.open = {}.", session.isOpen());
            if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
                isInternalTransaction = false;
                tx = session.getTransaction();
            } else {
                isInternalTransaction = true;
                tx = session.beginTransaction();
            }
            if (tx == null) {
                session.disconnect();
                return beginOperation(++level);
            }
            return session;
        }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see IOperationManager#commitOperation
     */
    @Override
    public void commitOperation() {
        if (isInternalTransaction && tx != null && tx.isActive())
            tx.commit();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see IOperationManager#rollbackOperation
     */
    @Override
    public void rollbackOperation() {
         if (isInternalTransaction && tx != null){
              tx.rollback();
    }

    public boolean isComitted() {
        return !tx.getStatus().isOneOf(TransactionStatus.ACTIVE);
    }
    }
```

Saving the date in the request:

```
   public void processRequest(){
    TransactionManager txmgr = new TransactionManager();
    try {
        Session session = txmgr.beginOperation();
        // [...] do the saving
        txmgr.commitOperation();
    } catch (PersistenceException ex){
        txmgr.rollbackOperation();
    }
}
```

As my configuration shows, the Hibernate Session uses the thread context, which I thinks binds the session to the Tomcat threads. This leads to the following problem:

When a transaction is rolled back, the underlying session will be corrupted (due to Hibernate internal stuff). Now each following request, that is processed by this thread, does fail with an error like this one: **org.hibernate.HibernateException: Calling method 'getCriteriaBuilder' is not valid without an active transaction (Current status: MARKED_ROLLBACK)**

The hibernate documentation states, that on a rollback the session has to be closed and a new one has to be generated. But how do I do that in combination with Apache Tomcat? As far as I understood each Tomcat thread is automatically assigned with a hibernate session. How can I tell Tomcat to get a new one? Or do I have to handle this manually?

Does anyone have an idea or further information, which helps me to solve my problem?

**UPDATE:** It looks like the rollback is not the reason for this error. At least I was able to trigger rollbacks and use the session afterwards. I suppose that I forgot to commit / rollback the transaction. This leads to a timeout which could cause my problems.

Comment: Did you try to use Spring to manage your transactions by AOP ? see https://o7planning.org/en/10307/spring-mvc-and-hibernate-transaction-tutorial

Comment: Why are you not explicitly calling `tx.rollback()`  in your `rollbackOperation()` method?

Comment: @stdunbar This was a mistake made during copying my code and removing the log statements. I updated it.

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD We don't use the spring framework in our project. We only use JSF ( Primefaces ) and Hibernate (5.3.6)

Comment: @Trynx91, i'm sorry for you about not using spring :)
About your issue, you should destroy or inactivate your transaction after the rollback in order that the besgin transaction method start a new one.

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD I'm actually doing that. If a transaction fails, it is getting rolled back. But If the same thread later tries to open a new transaction it fails, saying that it is impossible without an active transaction. The hibernate documentation states, that after rolling back a transaction, the underlying session get's corrupted. In my context theses sessions are bound to the thread. So my question was, how do I get this thread to reopen a new session.

Comment: Are you sure (by debug or log) that the tx.rollback(); is called ? After the rollback the code session.getTransaction().isActive() do return false ?

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD I'm pretty sure that tx.rollback(); is called. But to be a 100 percent sure I will test it today.

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD I checked it again. session.getTransaction().isActive() does return false after the rollback.

Comment: You do  not "Reopen sessions". YOu open new sessions